# get запрос и ошибка TypeError

Tags: python

всем привет! есть код, при помощи модуля requests отправляет GET запросы на сервер. В теле запроса есть ID задачи, с каждым запросом этот ID нужно увеличивать на 1. Вроде задача простая, но возникает ошибка TypeError на строке с запросом. я понять не могу- нельзя что ли в переменной число добавить к запросу или что??
Сам код:

```
import requests
import time
zadanie = '100' #с этого ID нужно начать
url = 'http://mysite.ru/task_id=' #основа url
for i in range (9999):
    r = requests.get (url + zadanie +'&user_id=1')
    zadanie += i #прибавляем к ID 1
    print (r.text)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте на:

```
zadanie = 100
```

**Без кавычек**

Так как `zadanie = '100'` имеет тип `string` вы не можете прибавить `integer`.

```
>>> type(i)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(zadanie)
<class 'str'>
```

Далее стоит изменить:

```
r = requests.get (url + str(zadanie) +'&user_id=1')
```

Comment: Всё-таки типы str и int

Comment: пробовал, тогда выдает ошибку тайперрор на линии zadanie += i #прибавляем к ID 1

Comment: Я исправил ответ.

Comment: да все заработало, спасибо! забыл про str()